# By default which selector is set to Checkbox

Tags: android, checkbox

I want to modify the default selector to use same drawable for enabled and disabled checkboxes. 
  For that i think i need to override selector for checkbox. 
  I need to use same device specific drawables.(No custom drawables).
  Thanks.

Comment: If you want to device specific drawables then what is need of selector here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Following is default selector for Checkbox

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2008 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Enabled states -->

    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_window_focused="false"
          android:state_enabled="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_on" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_window_focused="false"
          android:state_enabled="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_off" />

    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_pressed="true"
          android:state_enabled="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_on_pressed" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_pressed="true"
          android:state_enabled="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_off_pressed" />

    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="true"
          android:state_enabled="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_on_selected" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="true"
          android:state_enabled="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_off_selected" />

    <item android:state_checked="false"
          android:state_enabled="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_off" />
    <item android:state_checked="true"
          android:state_enabled="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_on" />


    <!-- Disabled states -->

    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_window_focused="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_on_disable" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_window_focused="false"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_off_disable" />

    <item android:state_checked="true" android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_on_disable_focused" />
    <item android:state_checked="false" android:state_focused="true"
          android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_off_disable_focused" />

    <item android:state_checked="false" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_off_disable" />
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:drawable="@drawable/btn_check_on_disable" />

</selector>
```

this is defined as `btn_check.xml` in to `sdk -> platforms -> API_VERSION -> data -> res -> drawable`